# Is it Okay to Snake Underground Line that has a Shielded Fernco Coupling?

Tags: drainage, pvc, underground

I need to tie-in a pvc pipe to an existing 4 in. pvc drain pipe. I plan to use a shielded fernco coupling. Is it okay to snake a pipe that has a fernco coupling? Will the snake tear up the fernco? The pipes are underground drainage lines that are outside of the house.

Comment: There's always that possibility  after many passes with an aggressive cutter head (like a spiral cutter or a serrated "C" cutter), but I believe the Code Gods would have  something to say against installing this kind of fitting and so far they haven't.

Comment: Typically the pipes will be nearly touching and the fernco just wraps around the outside of them. Do you anticipate a lot of fernco surface area showing to the inside of the pipes?

Comment: @Joe Phillips There will be a couple inch gap as I have to slide pipe back into the Y fitting's hub.